# Regex Capturing Javascript.js in cshtml file

Tags: javascript, regex

I looked and the closest answer I got was [capturing filename from url without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671522/regex-capture-filename-from-url-without-file-extention)

So I have this cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/javascript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/javascript2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i tried using this regex:

```
(?!.+[Ss]cripts+\/)\/+.+\.js
```

However, using Rad regex designer i am getting this result

- /javascript.js
- /javascript2.js

how can I capture just this

- javascript (without .js)
- javascript2 (without .js)

I will then use a replace expression

```
$&.min.
```

to come out with the final result

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/javascript2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a capturing group should accomplish what you want:

`((?!.+[Ss]cripts+\/)\/+.+)\.js`

This will still include the `/` at the beginning, but that should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

just want to add the following combination worked:

so i have a cshtml file with some script tags like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/javascript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then i used regex replace using MSbuild target as:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" RegexPattern="((?!.+[Ss]cripts+\/)\/+.+)\.js" Replacement="$1.min.js" Files="@(CSHTML)" />
```

right then and there the replacement expression `$1.min.js`

resulted to replace the

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/javascript.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```