# Regex - get the fileName?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this urls:

```
C:\Projects\Ensure_Solution\GD_EServices_Web\App_WebReferences\GD_Eservices_Web_Service\GD_Eservices_Web_Service.wsdl
C:\Projects\Ensure_Solution\GD_EServices_Web\App_WebReferences\GD_Eservices_Web_Service\GD_Eservices_Web_Service.wsdl
```

I want to get the wsdl file name ( no leading slash)

I have succeeded with 2 solutions :

```
\\[^\\]+$

\\(.(?!\\))+$
```

But this returns the leading slash : http://regexr.com?32lvi

[image]

how can I *enhance* my regex return **only** the file ?

Comment: `Please include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using, together with this tag,` says the `regex` tag description.

Comment: @LevLevitsky you are certainly right !. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to exclude the the leading slash in the regex.

```
var path = 'C:\\Projects\\Ensure_Solution\\GD_EServices_Web\\App_WebReferences\\GD_Eservices_Web_Service\\GD_Eservices_Web_Service.wsdl';
console.log(path.match(/[^\\]+$/));
```

And you could get it without regex, use `split`, and get the last element with `pop`:

```
console.log(path.split('\\').pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work `[^\\]+$`
But for your case I'd prefer smth like `string.split('/').pop()` (javascript) or `array_pop(split('/', string))` (for php, I don't know language you are using) not regexp.

Comment: I know this solution `.split('/').pop();` but the question tagged as regex.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the negative look-ahead `(?!\\)(.(?!\\))+$`

Comment: js supports netgative look ahead ?  or is it negative look behind i dont remember

Comment: @RoyiNamir lookbehinds of any case are not supported, lookaheads are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\\[^\\]+$
```

Note:that means try with only *one* leading backslash

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
([\w\d_-]*)\.?[^\\\/]*$
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671522/regex-capture-filename-from-url-without-file-extention) has some examples for javascript.

Alternatively, you can so a string split on "\" to create an array and get the last one in the array.