# remove text from url string javascript

Tags: javascript, url, replace

I want to display, with javascript, just the filename of the page the user is on. For example,

```
https://test.example.com/wow.html
```

should return

```
wow
```

I was trying to use the `replace()` method, like so:

```
var url = document.URL;
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = url.replace("http://test.example.com/", " ");
```

But I can't figure out how to remove the .html extension as well, or also replace https urls. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: after the replace you could do a `substring` upto the `indexOf` .html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3671574/1267304

Comment: possible duplicate of [REGEX: Capture Filename from URL without file extention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671522/regex-capture-filename-from-url-without-file-extention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible way to do it.

```
var url = "https://test.example.com/wow.html"

var urlSplit = url.split("/");
var name = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1].split(".")[0];
console.log(name);
```

// this will fail of course with a name like my.page.html but this is just to give another alternative. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a little hack using an `<a>` element that works as such:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com/foo.html";
parser.pathname; // => "/foo.html"
```

You can parse off the `/` and the `.html` however you want, but you'll always get the correct path back from `.pathname`.

See [here](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561) for more info about this method.

Comment: First, the OP doesn't want `.html` to be in the output. Second, I wonder why use parser instead of regular expression, any advantages??

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), like this:

```
"https://test.example.com/wow.html".match(/https?:\/\/test\.example\.com\/(\w*).html/)
// Returned list: ["https://test.example.com/wow.html", "wow"]
```

When starting out a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) can be useful to make sense of the expression:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "https://test.example.com/wow.html";
var new_text = text.slice(text.indexOf("//") + 2, text.indexOf(".html")).split('/');
console.log(new_text[1]);
```